# Language change in Ubuntu - files not transfered to new paths

Tags: 16.04, filesystem, language-support, system-language

Recently, I changed the system language in Ubuntu 16.04. from German to English. I was aksed whether I want to change the standard folder names from German to English (e.g. "Dokumente" to "Documents") which I agreed to. Now my desktop is empty and there are no files on it. If I open a terminal and enter `cd Schreibtisch` (Schreibtisch is the German name for "Desktop") I can still change to the old path. However, the other German paths, apparently, have been deleted/properly renamend. I have two questions on this matter:

1.) Why did the files not get transfered to "Desktop" from "Schreibtisch"?
2.) Is there a way to move all files at once from `~/Schreibtisch` to `~/Desktop`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you describe is intentional. Empty standard folders are simply renamed, while non-empty are not. The reason is to not break the old file paths automatically. New files saved to `~/Desktop` will end up in the new folder.

You can easily move the files; a command line way to do it is:

```
mv ~/Schreibtisch/* ~/Desktop
```

When you have made sure that all the files were moved correctly, you can remove `~/Schreibtisch`.