# How can I rename the Desktop folder after changing the system language?

Tags: filesystem, system-language

I just switched my Ubuntu system language from French to English. I have been asked if I wanted to create new folders (Desktop, Pictures, ...), I said yes. My old files were not moved, but now I have a Bureau (French for Desktop) and a Desktop folder. When I create a folder on my desktop using GUI, the folder is actually created in the old Bureau folder. What should I do to stop having the old French folders getting used (which I guess would also work for other folders)?

EDIT: it is not answered by [Language change in Ubuntu - files not transfered to new paths](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871347/language-change-in-ubuntu-files-not-transfered-to-new-paths) because it does not answer to why "When I create a folder on my desktop using GUI, the folder is actually created in the old Bureau folder"

It get fixed, probably when I restarted a second time.
So I needed to restart once for getting the new folders, and another time to get the GUI Desktop to work as expected.

Comment: Try to log out and log in again to make the system start using the new folders.

Comment: Yep, restarting the system a second time seems to have fixed it

Comment: `LANG=C xdg-user-dirs-update --force` ; `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

Answer (score 9):

Modify the folder entries in the `/home/<user>/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file to make them fit your needs, to do it just open a terminal and execute : `nano /home/<user>/.config/user-dirs.dirs`
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to close the file and confirm the changes by pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> - log out and back in ...

Note : Replace `<user>` in the provided command with ***your*** user name.
Here an example with the default content of the `user-dirs.dirs` file ->

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"  
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"  
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"  
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"  
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"  
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"  
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"  
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

When you change the content of ***your*** file to matching these entries, all folders should be in English.
Additionally check the `/home/<user>/.config/user-dirs.locale` file if the content is `en_US` or another English language, if it's not change it : `nano /home/<user>/.config/user-dirs.locale`

Note : Sometimes logging out and back in for whatever reason is not sufficient, but a reboot "fixes" it.

Comment: Probably that file looks like that already.

Comment: Why don't you make the paths in your answer relative? That way users wouldn't have to edit the commands

Comment: @someonewithpc More or less intentionally, right because it's generally not recommended to copy / paste something and execute it in a terminal, especially when it comes to commands which need elevated (root) privileges. But sure, in this special case not much harm would be done. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in that case it was not the solution, the files was like that already. It was fixed, probably just by restarting a second time the system.